# Colocar la primera letra de cada palabra en mayúscula en un Array

Tags: javascript, json, array

Estoy obteniendo de un llamado **GET** con Fetch los siguientes objetos

```
    {
    "name": "total_kills_knife",
    "value": 3063
    },
    {
    "name": "total_kills_hegrenade",
    "value": 341
    },
    {
    "name": "total_kills_glock",
    "value": 3970
    },
    {
    "name": "total_kills_deagle",
    "value": 2233
    },
    {
    "name": "total_kills_elite",
    "value": 94
    },
    {
    "name": "total_kills_fiveseven",
    "value": 1029
    },
    {
    "name": "total_kills_xm1014",
    "value": 271
    }
```

Lo que necesito es eliminar el fragmento de `total_kills_` y luego remplazar la primera letra minúscula por una mayúscula en todos los objetos, solo en `name`.
Quedando como por ejemplo el siguiente resultado:

```
    {
    "name": "Knife",
    "value": 3063
    },
```

Siguiendo mi lógica inicie con `replace` ya que se puede utilizar con **Expresiones Regulares** (RegExp).
Remover el `total_kills_` dentro de todo es tarea sencilla.

```js
var contenido = 
    [{
    "name": "total_kills_knife",
    "value": 3063
    },
    {
    "name": "total_kills_hegrenade",
    "value": 341
    },
    {
    "name": "total_kills_glock",
    "value": 3970
    },
    {
    "name": "total_kills_deagle",
    "value": 2233
    },
    {
    "name": "total_kills_elite",
    "value": 94
    },
    {
    "name": "total_kills_fiveseven",
    "value": 1029
    },
    {
    "name": "total_kills_xm1014",
    "value": 271
    }]

var data1 = JSON.stringify(contenido); 
data1 = data1.replace(/total_kills_*/g, "");
var data2 = JSON.parse(data1); 
console.log(data2)
```

El problema surge a la hora de solo remplazar la primera letra de minúscula a mayúscula.

Lo mas cerca que he estado fue lo siguiente

```js
var contenido = 
    [{
    "name": "total_kills_knife",
    "value": 3063
    },
    {
    "name": "total_kills_hegrenade",
    "value": 341
    },
    {
    "name": "total_kills_glock",
    "value": 3970
    },
    {
    "name": "total_kills_deagle",
    "value": 2233
    },
    {
    "name": "total_kills_elite",
    "value": 94
    },
    {
    "name": "total_kills_fiveseven",
    "value": 1029
    },
    {
    "name": "total_kills_xm1014",
    "value": 271
    }]

var data1 = JSON.stringify(contenido); 
data1 = data1.replace(/total_kills_*/g, "");
var data2 = JSON.parse(data1); 


var data3 = JSON.stringify(data2); // this is a string
data3 = data3.replace(/\b[a-z]/g,c=>c.toUpperCase());
var data4 = JSON.parse(data3); 
console.log(data4)
```

Al parecer funciona pero realiza el cambio tanto en `name` como en `value`, que no es el resultado deseado. 

¿Alguien sabe por que pasa esto y como puedo solucionarlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var contenido = 
    [{
    "name": "total_kills_knife",
    "value": 3063
    },
    {
    "name": "total_kills_hegrenade",
    "value": 341
    },
    {
    "name": "total_kills_glock",
    "value": 3970
    },
    {
    "name": "total_kills_deagle",
    "value": 2233
    },
    {
    "name": "total_kills_elite",
    "value": 94
    },
    {
    "name": "total_kills_fiveseven",
    "value": 1029
    },
    {
    "name": "total_kills_xm1014",
    "value": 271
    }];

//recorrer el arreglo
contenido.forEach(i => {
  // reemplazar total_kills_
  i.name = i.name.replace("total_kills_","");
  // i.name es igual al primer elemento en mayúscula más el 
  // resto de la palabra
  i.name = i.name[0].toUpperCase() + i.name.slice(1);
});

console.log(contenido);
```